# Using and extended type in an overriden method

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

I'm trying to create an abstract class that has a method that I want to take a param that is the same as or extends some base class. I thought it would be:

```
trait InputParams
abstract class A() {
  def input[T <: InputParams](datum: T) // abstract
  ...
}

case class ExtendedInputParams() extends InputParams
class B() extends A() {
  override def input[T <: InputParams](datum: T)...
  // the input(datum) method needs more to be able to treat datum as an
  // ExtendedInputParams, how do I do this?
  ...
}
```

in class B (I suspect A needs changes too) how do I define the `datum` type as `ExtendedInputParams`for `(new B).input(some-datum-of-type-ExtendedInputParams)` so the overriding `input` can treat `datum` as an `ExtendedInputParams` and still  enforce that it is extending `InputParams`? I also want to enforce that the method overrides the abstract method in class `A`.

**updated for clarity**

Comment: This `def input[ExtendedInputParams](datum: ExtendedInputParams)...` is the same thing as this `def input[T](datum:T)...`. You are _naming_ the type parameter. Giving it the same name as an existing type is confusing and indicates you might not know that's what you're doing.

Comment: There's a linter somewhere that will warn when your type param name hides a type name, because that mistake is not unheard of.

Comment: Of course I don't know what I'm doing, that is why I asked the question.

Comment: How do I give `T` a concrete type in this case? I thought I passed a concrete type to the type param of `input`. Then how do I declare the concrete type of `datum`?

Comment: updated the question to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To narrow the constraint in the subclass:

```
scala> class P ; class Q extends P
defined class P
defined class Q

scala> class A { type T <: P ; def f[X <: T](a: X) = a.toString }
defined class A

scala> class B extends A { type T = Q ; override def f[X <: T](a: X) = a.toString * 2 }
defined class B

scala> (new B).f(new Q)
res0: String = Q@1ea930ebQ@1ea930eb

scala> (new B).f(new P)
<console>:14: error: inferred type arguments [P] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [A <: Q]
       (new B).f(new P)
               ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : P
 required: A
       (new B).f(new P)
                 ^

scala> (new A { type T = P }).f(new P)
res3: String = P@4300e240
```

Reworded:

```
scala> class P ; class Q extends P { def q = 42 }
defined class P
defined class Q

scala> class X[T <: P] { def f[A <: T](a: A) = a.toString }
defined class X

scala> class Y[T <: Q] extends X[T] { override def f[A <: T](a: A) = a.q.toString }
defined class Y

scala> (new Y).f(new Q)
res0: String = 42
```

Comment: I may not have explained well above, edited for clarity.

Comment: `B.f` receives a `Q`, which extends `P`. I accidentally used `A` for a type param.

Comment: That's it, the second example. Just so I understand we used 2 type parms here, T and A. T was attached to the extended class in the declaration only so it could be used in the f function declaration in the extending class as bounds? So the type params are used as type and upper bounds.

Comment: T as type param or member works the same here. I think `type T = Q` is simpler. You could also just `def f(t: T)` depending on what you're doing.